# Connection reset when uploading files over specified limit in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am creating a small spring boot project and need to upload an image to be stored and served back to the users of the site. I have configured spring to reject requests larger than 10mb, and when uploading images under this limit the system functions fine. To deal with requests that are larger I have implemented a simple controlleradvice class. here is the relevant code

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MaxUploadController {
    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public String handleMaxSizeException(Model model, MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "File is too large!");
        model.addAttribute("event", new Event());
        System.out.println("Maximum file upload reached");
        return "createEvent";
    }
}
```

```
    @GetMapping("/events")
    public String events(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("events", eventRepo.findAllByOrderByEventIDDesc());
        return "Events";
    }

    @GetMapping("/createEvent")
    public String createEvents(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("event", new Event());
        return "createEvent";
    }

    @PostMapping("/createEvent")
    public String addEvent(@ModelAttribute Event event, Model model, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        event.setEventPicture(file.getBytes());
        eventRepo.save(event);
        return "redirect:/events";
    }
```

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/createEvent}" th:object="${event}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="image">Image: </label>
      <input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/jpeg"><br><br>

      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" th:field="*{name}" required><br><br>

      <label for="name">Location:</label>
      <input type="text" id="location" name="location" th:field="*{location}" required><br><br>

      <label for="name">Date:</label>
      <input type="text" id="date" name="date" th:field="*{date}" required><br><br>

      <label for="name">Time:</label>
      <input type="text" id="time" name="time" th:field="*{time}" required><br><br>

      <label for="name">Description:</label>
      <input type="text" id="description" name="description" th:field="*{description}" required><br><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Create">
    </form>
```

and for configuration

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size = 10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size = 15MB
```

on attempting to upload a 12mb image the console logs

```
Maximum file upload reached
2024-02-11T23:37:14.821Z  WARN 16338 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size exceeded]
Maximum file upload reached
2024-02-11T23:37:15.815Z  WARN 16338 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size exceeded]
```

and the browser displays

`This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.`

on inspection of the network usage, the request never makes it past initial connection